# Docker build fail: sharp Use with musl 1.2.2 requires manual installation of libvips

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I am running this command
`docker build -t project`
and on step 13 the installation fails
here is docker file contents

```
### Base
FROM node:12-alpine as base
ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN apk update --no-cache
RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app

USER node
WORKDIR /app

# Copy base dependencies describing
COPY --chown=node:node ./src ./src
COPY --chown=node:node ./static ./static
COPY --chown=node:node ./nest-cli.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node ./package*.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node ./tsconfig*.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node ./.env.${NODE_ENV} ./

RUN npm install --only=production


### Builder
FROM base as builder

RUN npm install --only=development
RUN npm run build


### Runtime
FROM node:12-alpine as runtime
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app

# Copy runtime dependencies
COPY --chown=node:node --from=base /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=base /app/.env.${NODE_ENV} ./
COPY --chown=node:node --from=base /app/package.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node --from=base /app/static ./static
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/dist ./dist

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

It fails on

> RUN npm install --only=production

I believe it's caused by node image, what would you suggest to resolve this issue? Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is Error stack that appears in console

```
> sharp@0.27.2 install /app/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

ERR! sharp Use with musl 1.2.2 requires manual installation of libvips >= 8.10.5
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to
```

Comment: One of the things that makes Alpine-based images smaller is using a package called musl libc in place of the "normal" GNU libc, but there are occasional compatibility problems.  Does deleting the word `-alpine` in the various `FROM` lines help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue was resolved by updating node-alpine to 14 and updating sharp library to 0.29.1